# How to call a method of anonymous object php?

Tags: php, anonymous-types

I need to create anonymous object and call it's method

```php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Greeting = function (string $d){return "Hello ".$d;};
$greetings = $obj->Greeting("world!");
```

But when I try to execute this code I get an error

`Call to undefined method stdClass::Greeting()`

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a stdClass object, not an [anonymous one](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php):

```php
$obj = new class () {
    public function Greeting(string $d)
    {
        return "Hello $d";
    }
};
echo $greetings = $obj->Greeting("world!");
```

output:

```
Hello world!
```

---

> What's wrong?

Nothing, let's just ask, what's behind or happening here?

The stdClass is used for "empty" objects in PHP or when casting an array to an object (`$obj = (object) ['hello' => 'world']`).

By default it has no properties (like in `$obj = new stdClass;`) and also no methods. It is empty in terms of both of these.

Properties can be added dynamically to an `stdClass` object - but not functions as class methods have to be declared in PHP before instantiating the object.

So the function in your case is a property (PHP has two bags here: one for properties and one for functions) and not a new method dynamically added to it (`class MyClass { function method() {...} }`).

Let's compare with the original example and provoke the error again:

```php
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->Greeting = function (string $d) {
    return "Hello $d";
};
$greetings = $obj->Greeting("world!");
```

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::Greeting()
```

However:

```php
echo $greetings = ($obj->Greeting)("world!");
                  #              #
```

works, the output:

```
Hello world!
```

because PHP is now guided to "call" the `($obj->Greeting)` property indirectly, so not looking for the `stdClass::Greeting` method first.

Normally you don't want that indirection, therefore the suggestion to use the anonymous class instead.

Comment: Oh, thanks. My bad.

Comment: No problems, this was a bit of a shot into the sky from my end as well, as I didn't know if you exactly meant/needed this.

Comment: I am just writing test for method that get values from db, and instead of using db I created pseudo repository with this anonymous class. Thats it.

Comment: Use the anonymous class then in the test, it's better for mocks. I extended the answer for completeness trying to explain why the earlier attempt didn't work out, but regardless, go with [anonymous classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php), they give you better utility in tests.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$obj->Greeting("world!");
```

to

```
($obj->Greeting)("world!");
```

or use call_user_func() :

```
call_user_func($obj->Greeting, 'world!')
```